# React + webpack: 'process.env' is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to run the hot dev server on our site with webpack; the site uses ReactJS, which has this code in it:

```
if (\"production\" !== process.env.NODE_ENV) // etc
```

When not running hot-swap it's fine, but with the hot-swap, it gets run, resulting in the error:

```
TypeError: process.env is undefined
```

The code looks like this:

[image: error is on this line]

The project is modelled after https://github.com/webpack/react-starter which *does* work; so the question is; what error have I made in the config file and/or how do I go about looking for the error when the 'production' compilation works just fine?

I've posted the [gist of the webpack config file](https://gist.github.com/haf/f671f1113d2c5dead5a7).

Comment: This answer made more sense to me. Posting for others with the same need for a complete example. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/868

Comment: What is `with hot-swap`? `hot dev server`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264701/470749 points to Webpack docs saying that `process.env` should no longer be used in the frontend.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your webpack config, there are two options that can affect `process.env`:

- [When you specify `config.target`](https://gist.github.com/haf/f671f1113d2c5dead5a7#file-gistfile1-txt-L121) (see [`config.target`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target))
- [When you define the `process.env` variable via `DefinePlugin`](https://gist.github.com/haf/f671f1113d2c5dead5a7#file-gistfile1-txt-L110)

Looking at your code, it looks like `process.env` might be undefined when both `options.prerender` and `options.minimize` are `false`.

You could fix this by always using an environment that defines `process.env` (ex: `node`), or by using `DefinePlugin` to assign a default value to the variable yourself.

Comment: When you use Webpack to package a server-side app (`target: 'node'`), the `DefinePlugin` seems to overwrite `process.env` i.s.o. adding to it. I had trouble reading the Heroku env. variable `process.env.PORT` until I removed the `DefinePlugin` from my webpack config.

Comment: I defined my env variables inside my .env file and was wondering why the variables were coming up undefined in my code. Turns out I also needed to include 

```new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
        }
      }), 
```
in my webpack config! Thank you! That was helpful.

Answer (score 9):

This is the simplest way:

```
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin( { ...process.env } )
```

Add that to your list of webpack plugins.

Comment: This worked for me... except, you may want to be more explicit if you have keys or secrets in your environment, because this pulls EVERYTHING.

Comment: Well in docker you need to pull everything, and if you don't "docker" then you're not in 2018 :P

Comment: Yeah you really shouldn't do that or you'll probably end up leaking secrets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using create-react-app and you use webpack

```
Install npm install dotenv-webpack --save-dev
```

And then configure your webpack config file this way

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  // other webpack config options
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv() //<---
  ]
};
```

Note: Be sure you have your .env or .env.development in rhe root of your project, and that your environment variables begin with REACT_APP_. Example

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://example.com/api
```

Hope this help someone!