# Webpack: process.env undefined using DefinePlugin and DotEnv

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to get my variable from my .env file but I always get `undefined`

This is my js code :

```
require('dotenv').config();
class Header extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){...}
    render(){
        console.log("NODE ENV", process.env.NODE_ENV);
        console.log("REACT_APP_MYAPP", process.env.REACT_APP_MYAPP);
        ...
   }
}
```

This prints :

> NODE_ENV development
>
> REACT_APP_MYAPP `undefined`

In my package.json there is :

```
"scripts":{
      "start" : "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
      "build" : "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
 }
```

And in my webpack.dev.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge.smart(common, {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        hot: true,
        overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
        },
        inline :true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 8085
    },
    devtool: "inline-sourcemap",
    optimization: {
        namedModules: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModulReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
            "process.env.REACT_APP_MYAPP": JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_MYAPP)
        })
    ],
    mode: "development"
});
```

And I placed my .env file at the root of my project, next to webpack.dev.js and package.json:

> REACT_APP_MYAPP=http://localhost:8080/

So I think, it doesn't success to get the variable in the file.

How can I get the **REACT_APP_MYAPP** value in the code please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React + webpack: 'process.env' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096018/react-webpack-process-env-is-undefined)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First solution by adding REACT_APP_MYAPP in start didn't worked.
But second solution worked.

SOLUTION:

Adding `require('dotenv').config()` file inside my `webpack.dev.js` and replacing :

```
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
        "process.env.REACT_APP_MYAPP": JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_MYAPP)
    })
```

with

```
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'REACT_APP_MYAPP']);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

Journeying through the deep, dark rabbit hole will lead you to the following facts:

- Webpack 5 no longer provides `process` or [other Node.js variables](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11282).
- The role of `DefinePlugin` requires redefining.
- Values passed to `DefinePlugin` must be [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), even if they're strings.
- `EnvironmentPlugin` makes things more confusing, given Webpack 5.
- `process.env` isn't really something you should be using in the frontend.
- You can use [polyfills](https://sanchit3b.medium.com/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5-905c1f5504a0) to re-add `process` and others back in, but there is [a reason it's no longer available](https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/blob/master/MIGRATION%20GUIDE.md#user-content-level-5-runtime-errors).
- [dotenv-wepack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) is neither necessary nor the way to go.
- The reason for using `process.env` is to access variables globally. But it's a passenger on the wrong flight. We can drop it and instead just access the intended variable directly:

```
plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
        // With dotenv (values must be stringified)
        ...Object.entries(dotenv.config().parsed).reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [`${curr[0]}`]: JSON.stringify(curr[1]) }), {}),
        
        // Without dotenv 
        'myString': JSON.stringify('IAmAString')
    })
  ]
```

In the frontend:

```
declare var myString: string;
console.log(myString); // 'IAmAString'
```

If you have several objects with variables it makes sense to abstract the stringification:

```
// Create a function to stringify values
function stringifyValues(object: {[key: string]: any;}){
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [`${curr[0]}`]: JSON.stringify(curr[1]) }), {} as { [key: string]: string; });
}

// use with DefinePlugin
plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      ...stringifyValues(dotenv.config().parsed),
      ...stringifyValues(dotenv.config({ path: '/.env.special' }).parsed),
      'myObject': stringifyValues({ 
            name: 'Object', 
            description: 'to be an object' 
      })
    })
  ]
```

If you *really* want access to `process.env`:

```
plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
        // this might expose confidential data about your environment
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env),

        // the correct way
        'process.env.USERNAME': JSON.stringify('Donald Hump')
    })
  ]
```

In the frontend:

```
declare var process: any;
console.log(process) // will NOT work, because process hasn't been injected
console.log(process.env); // will work but risky
console.log(process.env.USERNAME); // correct: 'Donald Hump'
```

Comment: Thank you! for me the issue was that I was destructuring the process.env: `const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;` which did not work. instead const `NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;` works.

Comment: `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config().parsed) })` also works

Comment: Thank you so much for the well researched answer. However, I'm still not sure what the best practice is

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you could make this work.

The easiest to test is to change your `"start" : "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",` to   `"start" : "REACT_APP_MYAPP=http://localhost:8080/ node webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",`

This will inject the environment variable and it will be available during the webpack build process. You can use this technique whenever using `npm` or `node` to run a command. For instance, `NODE_ENV='development REACT_MY_APP=http://localhost:8080/ node myapp.js` and both will be available on `process.env`.

You could also call your `require('dotenv').config()` file inside your `webpack.dev.js`. Then it would be set during your usage of the DefinePlugin.

Generally, you don't use the `npm start` command to run your development server.

As the application grows you should look at the [Webpack Environment Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin#usage-with-default-values). Then you can use the .env for the "production" build settings, requiring it in the production webpack.prod.js, while setting your default/fallback environment variables using the plugin.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use npm start for my dev server ?

Comment: When deploying for production, most default solutions will run `npm start` to kick off the application (after running `npm build`). This isn't forced. You could create a `start:production`, but it would be run as `npm run start:production`...so it's more just following the "default assumption". It also doesn't require the `run` in front of the `npm` command.

Comment: I will test to confirm, but looks like running webpack-dev-server is not passing the ENV_VARS into the process it runs webpack in. I think adding `node` in front would fix this. Also, if your application is going to be only client side, and you're uploading all the build files to be statically served then having `npm start` run the devServer doesn't really matter, as you won't be running a "production" node.js server to kick off the build. That would be more important if this was a "Server Side Rendered" (SSR) React App.

Comment: You absolutely should not use .env files in your production, or even include them in your source control.  Follow 12 Factor app development:

"Apps sometimes store config as constants in the code. This is a violation of twelve-factor, which requires strict separation of config from code. Config varies substantially across deploys, code does not."

Comment: This debate over strict 12-factor pans out at work a lot. Modern webpack built apps require funky hacks unless you allow for per environment builds.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in my custom React app model, only if I do not include 'REACT_APP_' in variable names:

in webpack.config.js:

```
// Node import
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = [
   plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'API'])
  ],
]
```

in .env:

```
NODE_ENV=development
API=http://localhost:5000
```

When I deploy the app though (on Netlify for example), I exclude NODE_ENV from the production environment variables.